# Cannot add into set in an onTap

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm following the [Write Your First App tutorial, part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#4) on Flutter (with some liberties with layout and identifier naming) and I'm having trouble. I can't seem to get the `onTap` to work. Here's my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: SuggestedNamesPage(title: 'Suggested Names'),
    );
  }
}

class SuggestedNamesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SuggestedNamesPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _SuggestedNamesPageState createState() => _SuggestedNamesPageState();
}

class _SuggestedNamesPageState extends State<SuggestedNamesPage> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _fave = Set<WordPair>();

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider();
        final int n = i ~/ 2;
        if (n >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[n]);
      });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    final isFavorite = _fave.contains(pair);
    return  ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color : isFavorite ? Colors.red : null,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (isFavorite) {
            _fave.add(pair);
          } else {
            _fave.remove(pair);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Suggested Names'),
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }

}
```

The individual `ListTile` is getting that ink splash effect but nothing is added to `_fave`. Am I missing something?

I'd also like to point out that the `onTap` is also missing from the [example code](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/startup_namer/step6_add_interactivity/lib/main.dart).

Also, here's the output of `flutter --version`:

```
Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (3 weeks ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
Engine • revision 52c7a1e849
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)
```

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint in the `if (isFavorite)`, are you even getting into the if-statement? The splash animation is working, it doesn't mean that your setState is working. Something is not working in there. Maybe the _fave is not bound to any UI state, so changing it isn't rebuilding any UI as you would like i suppose.

Comment: @HarounHajem I can't seem to get breakpoints to work, but `print` statements slipped into those `if` blocks do output something, so yes. I am getting into it.

Comment: Could you print the count, length, of the list _fave in the print statement, to see if the items is added and kept in the list, so the list isn't resetting it self upon every rebuild? I've read your code and it should work. Strange.. =(

Comment: @HarounHajem It always outputs `0`.

Comment: Ahaa the if statement is checking the favourite and then adding it, and since the pair is never in a favourite its never added. Just switch the _fave.add to the else and switch the _fave.remove to the if statement. Like this: if(favourite){_fave.remove(pair)}else{_fave.add(pair)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-statement is checking for favorite and then adding it, and since the pair is never in a favorite its never added.

You should switch the `.add` and `.remove` methods like this:

```
setState(() {
  if (isFavorite) {
    _fave.remove(pair);
  } else {
    _fave.add(pair);
  }
});
```